# Не получается зайти на виртуальный диск VirtualBox Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

До этого нормально заходил точно также, сейчас выскакивает Try or Install Ubuntu, хотя диск тот же и все работало.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выньте виртуальный CD из виртуального CD-ROM. Он стоит в очереди загрузки раньше вашего виртуального диска и перехватывает управление.

Comment: Спасибо большое